If $f(x) + f(f(x))$ is linear, then is $f$ linear?
The question came to me after watching a video on YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_kVrljSYt_8
I know that the function $g(x) = f(x) + f(f(x))$ is linear and therefore it holds that $g(ax+bx) = ag(x) + bg(x).$
That is, $$f(ax+bx) + f(f(ax+bx)) = a( f(x) + f(f(x)) ) + b( f(x) + f(f(x)) ) = af(x) + bf(x) + af(f(x)) + bf(f(x)).$$
But I think this does not mean that $f(ax+bx) = af(x) + bf(x)$ nor that $f(f(ax+bx)) = af(f(x)) + bf(f(x)).$

Is the domain the real numbers?

Recall that the solution to $ f(x) + f(f(x)) = Ax + B$ (in most cases) is going to look like $ f(x) = Cx + D [ (  -1  + \sqrt{ 4A+1}  ) / 2 ]^n + E [ (  -1   - \sqrt{ 4A+1}  ) / 2 ]^n$, which is almost certainly not linear. Furthermore, $D, E$ are going to be unique to the orbit of $f^n(x)$, and so even if we ended up with a linear solution, we can choose different values for the orbits which gives us a non-linear solution. This is what peter essentially did, where $ A = 0 $ yields a linear $f(x)$, but by changing the orbit, we get a piecewise linear solution.

Assuming the domain is the reals...
Say $f(x)=-1$, if $x> 0$, $f(x)=1$, if $x<0$, and $f(0)=0$.
Then $f(x) + f(f(x))=0$, so $f + f\circ f$ is linear. But, of course, $f$ is not linear.
